# Control audio file with one button

Tags: raspbian

I would like to create a simple audio player with Python which is controlled with one button. When I press the button the first time, the .wav should begin playing, but how can I stop it when the button is pressed again?

I´m using the command line:

os.system("aplay /sound.wav")

I tried it also with pygame, that worked, but when the Pi ran longer then 6 hours it played a teribble noise.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on subprocess.popen... in 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.popen#subprocess.Popen

But a simple way using import os is:  (I used ping rather than aplay for testing, as it also runs 'forever')  the close kills the subprocess.

```
import os
# do what you need to do to sense the button pushed 
p = os.popen('ping 192.168.2.1')
# do what you need to do to sense the button pushed 
p.close()
```